# How to get all todos from firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

[image: Firebase structure]

I have todos stored in firebase db, how can i get all the todos at once in a json array, with angularjs. so i can write something like this.

```html
<p ng-repeat="todo in todos">
  {{todo.title}}
</p>
```

Or is it the wrong structure to store todos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the extra `todo` key in your data structure. Try a structure like this:

```
{
  "todos": {
    "larohj5wj4qj_34qk": {
       "title": "Do homework",
       "checked": true
    },
    "utpAbn_48q5jrfKFf": {
       "title": "Walk dog",
       "checked": false
    }
  }
}
```

Then use AngularFire to synchronize this collection: *[code format done with Angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)*

**[Plnkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/yraUR2Divshx6ZrhXvC6?p=preview)**

```
angular.module('todoApp', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
  .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
  .controller('TodoCtrl', TodoController);

function TodoController($scope, rootRef, $firebaseArray) {
  $scope.todos = $firebaseArray(rootRef.child('todos');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but i tried in plunkr getting apply already in progress error.
plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7MDk3ZRhJ7e1TnvvYibu?p=preview

Comment: There were a few missing pieces in your plnkr repo, check out my updated version: http://plnkr.co/edit/yraUR2Divshx6ZrhXvC6?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, first you need to install **AngularFire** and add the dependency in your `index.html`

Then, you need to add the reference to your database in your service:

```
   factory('ToDosManager', ['$firebase', function ($firebase) {

      var ref = new Firebase("https://example123456789.firebaseio.com/");

      return {
        all: function() {
          return $firebase(ref).$asArray();
        },
        get: function(toDoId) {

          return otherTodo[toDoId];
        }
      }
    }])
```

then call your service from you controller

```
    $scope.getTodos = function(){
$scope.todos = ToDosManager.all();
```

Comment: This is a pre 1.0 version of AngularFire. Only 1.0 and above are officially supported by Firebase.